# What is the dictionary definition and the part of speech of the word "rival" used in “rival T-shirts”?

Tags: parts-of-speech, word-meaning

I came across the phrase like "wear rival T-shirts". I'm not sure which is the matching definition of the word "rival" in dictionaries and what is its part of speech —— a noun?

The phrase is in this sentence:

> the Rubios wore **rival T-shirts**. “Mr. Right,” read his. “Mrs. Always Right,” declared hers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> RIVAL
>
> noun
>
> 1.a person or thing competing with another for the same objective or for superiority in the same field of activity: I have two favorite teams, Arsenal, and any team playing their rival, Tottenham.

*The Rubios* is shorthand for a married couple. *Mr. Right* is the husband and *Mrs. Always Right* is the wife. They are rivals only in a *tongue-in-cheek* sense.

I.E. this was a play on the word designed to draw a laugh.